# How can the size of the dot marker be specified in terms of pixels

Tags: scilab

I found that the size of the dots produced in the following plot command are too large for the detail that I'm trying to show.

```
plot(x,y,".","MarkerSize",0);
```

Is it possible to specify the size of the dot in terms of its diameter using the number of pixels?  ...or, is there a better way?

**I'm using scilab 5.1.1 on msWindows**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know (Scilab 5.5.0 on Linux), Polyline entities expose a 'mark_size' property.

```
plot(0:9, 0:9, 'b-d'); // "y = x" with blue diamonds
curr_entity = gce(); // Handle of type "Compound"
curr_polyline = curr_entity.children; // Handle of type "Polyline"
curr_polyline.mark_size = 10; // Enjoy ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no answers have been posted since this question was posted, I will take that as meaning that what I have asked to do can't be done -- thus closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

As in Simone Libutti example you may specify the units used as size measure:

```
curr_polyline.mark_size = 10;
curr_polyline.mark_size_unit = "point";
```

I hope it helps.